# Passing and modifying mutlidimensional arrays in C/C++

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I'm having a problem with arrays and pointers, and although I thin I know what I'm doing wrong I'm unable to find a simple solution.

I have this piece of code:

```
void faceRotateACW(char *face[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM]){
    char tempFace[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM];
    for (int y=0;y<CUBE_DIM;y++){
        for (int x=0;x<CUBE_DIM;x++){
            tempFace[y][CUBE_DIM-x]=face[x][y];
        }
    }
    for (int a=0;a<CUBE_DIM;a++){
        for (int b=0;b<CUBE_DIM;b++){
            face[a][b]=tempFace[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know that the problem is that I'm trying to assign a char pointer to a char and that is a no-no, but how can I duplicate, then modify the array and push it back into the one passed by reference? How do I get at the values within the array I'm passing into the function?

Ok, all is going well, at least I'm starting to understand the problem better now (thanks folks).  I need to give more info though as the way I'm using this function is probably not the best way either, let me clarify.

I define the array as:

```
char *faces[NUM_FACES][CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM]={{{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}},
        {{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}},
        {{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}},
        {{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}},
        {{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}},
        {{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"},{"o","o","o"}}};
```

However when I call the function I'm trying to strip off the outer array like so:

```
 faceRotateACW(faces[currentFace]);
```

Sorry for mucking you all about folks, It's my first post :)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to do - do you want to pass an array of arrays (aka matrix) of char-pointers and simply swap these char pointers in your matrix? If so, why do you create a matrix of chars and not a matrix of char-pointers?

Comment: I'm trying to pass in the matrix values, rotate them and replace the values passed in. Am I passing pointers rather than values within the matrix?

Comment: The question is what the values actually are. Are the values `char`s or are they `char *`s? If they are `char`s read Johns answer, if they are `char *`s, read dbaupps and Yakovs answers. Or who am I kidding - read all answers! ;)

Comment: @PhilHolden - so your argument is 2D array of strings and the signutare is ->void faceRotateACW(char* face[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM])
My solution deals with this case

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the top.

In your `main` function (or whoever calls `faceRotateACW`), you have an array like

```
char theFace[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM];
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to / replaced with / "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array.

If you call your function as

```
rotateFaceACW(theFace);
```

the expression `theFace` in the function call will be replaced with an expression of type "pointer to CUBE_DIM-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[CUBE_DIM]`.  Thus, your function prototype would need to look something like

```
void rotateFaceACW(char (*face)[CUBE_DIM]) {...}
```

*or*

```
void rotateFaceACW(char face[][CUBE_DIM]) {...}
```

which in this context is the same thing.  You'd treat it as a normal array in the function:

```
void rotateFaceACW(char (*face)[CUBE_DIM])
{
  char tempFace[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM];
  ...
      tempFace[y][(CUBE_DIM-1)-x] = face[x][y];  // thanks Anthales
  ...
      face[x][y] = tempFace[x][y];
```

Since `face` is a pointer to the first element of the array `theFace`, any changes made in `rotateFaceACW` will be reflected in `theFace`.

Since it looks like you're always going to be dealing with NxN matrices whose size is constant (CUBE_DIM), you *probably* don't need to pass the number of rows explicitly, but in the general case you would need to.

If you wanted to deal with 2D arrays of *any* number of rows and columns, you'll have to take a different approach, which I won't go into here since it doesn't seem relevant to your issue.

Comment: Adding obligatory comment about writing `CUBE_DIM-1-x` instead of `CUBE_DIM-x`.

Comment: I didn't even see the overflow until I read Yakovs answer, so no credit to me please ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you try to transpose "in reverse columns order " the matrix of strings.
Following implementation does it in O(1) space and O(CUBE_DIM^2) time

```
void faceRotateACW(char* face[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM])
{
    for (int i = 0;i< CUBE_DIM;++i) {
        for (int j = i; j<CUBE_DIM;++j) {
            char* tmpFace = face[i][j];
            face[i][j] = face[j][i];
            face[j][i] = tmpFace;
        }
        for (int j = 0;j < CUBE_DIM/2;++j) {
            char* tmpFace = face[i][j];
            face[i][j] = face[i][CUBE_DIM - 1 - j];
            face[i][CUBE_DIM - 1 - j] = tmpFace;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a much better algorithm to use, but it doesn't actually answer the question, because `face` is meant to contain just `char`s not `char*`s.

Comment: @dbaupp - so he has to "transpose" the 2D matrix of chars,when he gets a pointer to this matrix?

Comment: I believe so, your code is correct after replacing `char* face` with `char (*face)`, `face` with `(*face)` elsewhere, and `char* tmpFace` with `char tmpFace`.

Comment: @dbaupp-pls look at his comment - the argument is 2D array of strings

Comment: yep, I saw that, that what my most recent comment was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pointer array. The syntax will be like this 
faceRotateACW(char *face[],int cube_dim)
then you can access all values in the multi-dimentional array and then change those values.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined it, you are passing a `CUBE_DIM`×`CUBE_DIM` matrix of pointers to `char`s, *not* a pointer to a `CUBE_DIM`×`CUBE_DIM` matrix of `char`s. To fix this, you should use

```
char (*face)[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM]
```

to indicate that `face` is the pointer, rather than the values stored in the array. Once you've done this, the code will no longer compile because `face[x][y]` (it is `char[]`) is the wrong type to assign to, and be assigned from, `tempFace[_][_]` (which is a `char`).

You can tell this because `face[x]` dereferences the outer layer of pointers of `face` (with an offset of `x`), and so has type `char[][]`. The `[y]` now strips off one layer of `[]` so the type of `face[x][y]` is `char[]`, *not* `char`.

To fix this, we need to get to the array that `face` points to before we start indexing, i.e. we need to dereference `face` and then index. That is:

```
(*face)[x][y]
```

So the final code is:

```
void faceRotateACW(char (*face)[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM]){
    char tempFace[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM];
    for (int y=0;y<CUBE_DIM;y++){
        for (int x=0;x<CUBE_DIM;x++){
            tempFace[y][CUBE_DIM-1-x]=(*face)[x][y];
        }
    }
    for (int a=0;a<CUBE_DIM;a++){
        for (int b=0;b<CUBE_DIM;b++){
            (*face)[a][b]=tempFace[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One might add, that a call to this function looks like `faceRotateACW(&mat)` if `mat` is declared as `char mat[CUBE_DIM][CUBE_DIM]`. Also there's an overflow in the first loop; should read `CUBE_DIM-1-x`